# code/ID returned after executing adb.exe devices command

Tags: android, adb

I am new to android app development, i need some info about adb.exe devices command.

When we execute a command `"adb.exe devices"` to see the connected android devices it returns a ID ex:- for samsung it returns a ID `"7a0d5da2"` (DeviceId).

I would like to know what is this code and is it different for HTC/any other android devices.

Answer (score 0):

This Device ID is supposed to be unique for every device. Which is true for commercial products from most decent vendors. It is based on the serial number the device reports to the USB stack during USB enumeration.